# How to execute something similar to a goto statement in node js or how to create and call a function within an asynchronous function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, tesseract, puppeteer

I am running an automated test through puppeteer that fills up a form and checks for captcha as well. If the captcha is incorrect, it refreshes to a new image but then I need to process the whole image again and reach the function which was used earlier to process it.

```
(async function example() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  /*-----------NEED TO COME BACK HERE-----------*/
  const tessProcess = utils.promisify(tesseract.process);
  await page.setViewport(viewPort)
  await page.goto('http://www.example.com')
  await page.screenshot(options)
  const text = await tessProcess('new.png');
  console.log(text.trim());
  await page.$eval('input[id=userEnteredCaptcha]', (el, value) => el.value = value, text.trim())
  await page.$eval('input[id=companyID]', el => el.value = 'val');
  const submitBtn = await page.$('[id="data"]');
  await submitBtn.click();


  try {
   var x =  await page.waitFor("#msgboxclose");
    console.log("Captcha error")
}
catch (e) {
    console.error('No Error');
}
if(x){
  await page.keyboard.press('Escape');

  /*---------GO FROM HERE--------*/
}

})()
```

I want to sort of create a loop so that the image can be processed again whenever the captcha is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a boolean variable that indicates whether you need to try again or not, and put the repeated functionality inside a `while` loop that checks that variable. If the `x` condition at the end of the loop is not fulfilled, set `tryAgain` to `false`, so that no further iterations occur:

```
(async function example() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  let tryAgain = true;  // <--------------------------
  while (tryAgain) {    // <--------------------------
    /*-----------NEED TO COME BACK HERE-----------*/
    const tessProcess = utils.promisify(tesseract.process);
    await page.setViewport(viewPort)
    await page.goto('http://www.example.com')
    await page.screenshot(options)
    const text = await tessProcess('new.png');
    console.log(text.trim());
    await page.$eval('input[id=userEnteredCaptcha]', (el, value) => el.value = value, text.trim())
    await page.$eval('input[id=companyID]', el => el.value = 'val');
    const submitBtn = await page.$('[id="data"]');
    await submitBtn.click();


    try {
      var x =  await page.waitFor("#msgboxclose");
      console.log("Captcha error")
    }
    catch (e) {
      console.error('No Error');
    }
    if(x){
      await page.keyboard.press('Escape');
      /*---------GO FROM HERE--------*/
    } else {
      tryAgain = false;   // <--------------------------
    }
  }

})()
```